# How to check Mnesia database of ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, mnesia

I want to access Mnesia database of ejabberd server, But i don't know how to read,write and update the data, Is there a way by which i can do this. 
Can i change Database to MySQL rather than Mnesia.
I have tried this

```
{odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost", "xmpp_db", "root", "**********"}}.
```

Here "xmpp_db" is the name of my database which is created for ejabberd, But i does not see any change in xmpp_db.
Should i create any tables in "xmpp_db", But problem is what are the names of my tables and fields.
I also have used

```
ejabberdctl dump /tmp/ejabberd.db.txt
```

command, But this is just for read the data(the data is in very roughly format and hard to understand). Is there any way by which i can perform read, write and update operations on Mnesia database.

your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way by which i can perform read, write and update operations on Mnesia database?

**General Info:**

Using `ejabberdctl` you can get a list of Mnesia general information, tables, records count, directory of its file and etc.

```
$ ejabberdctl mnesia [info]
```

**Data Manipulation:**

One way for reading Mnesia records is by attach to ejabberd console and call `mnesia:dirty_read/2` function with desired arguments.

```
$ ejabberdctl debug
1> mnesia:dirty_read(passwd, {<<"username">>, <<"host">>}).
[{passwd,{<<"username">>,<<"host">>}, <<"password">>}]
```

Also for updating (or writing) Mnesia records you can  call `mnesia:dirty_write/2` function the same way.

```
$ ejabberdctl debug
1> mnesia:dirty_write({passwd, {<<"user">>, <<"host">>, <<"new-pass">>}).
ok
```

For learning other Mnesia's API check its [official manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL indeed. As described in documentation, you need to configure MySQL connection and decide which module will use it.

You can read doc here: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#database-and-ldap-configuration

And them you need to configure back-end / method for relevant module. For example, for authentification, you need to set auth_method to odbc:

`auth_method: odbc`